# Load <img> html tag before js masonry

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

My problem is jQuery Masonry arranges my 'bricks' right away and don't wait images to load in.  Also I want images to be responsive so I cant define something like:

```
<img src="asas" height= "100px" width="100px" alt="asas">
```

The link for the live example is [here](http://atiweb.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code within window on `load` handler, or use [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) plugin which has been written by masonry author.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#wrapper').masonry({ ... });
});
```

or:

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');
$wrapper.imagesLoaded({
   done: function() {
        $wrapper.masonry({ ... });
   }
})
```

```
#wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm interested to know if this works. From what I can see, until each image has loaded its ratio is not known so its height isn't yet defined so I would have thought the answer would be to wait until all images have loaded before applying the masonry.

Comment: `load` event fires when all images are loaded, however, with masonry I prefer to use `imagesLoaded` plugin. `load` event is deprecated.

Comment: @RichardA. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182016/what-is-the-difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready

Comment: Thanks a lot, i thought document.ready is the same. also could you recommend me some jquery/javascript book?