# window.onload function doesn't work on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, onload, mozilla

I'm using a loading screen for a webpage and I use window.onload function.

Everything works great except in Mozilla Firefox browsers. When we first visit or refresh the page with ctrl+F5 combination, the loading screen never disappears. if we refresh the page only with F5, then it works.

I use the code below

```
$(window).load(function(e) {
    $("#body-mask").fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

I have also tried the code below but nothing changed.

```
window.onload = function () {
   $("#body-mask").fadeOut(1000,function(){
       $(this).remove();
   });
}
```

Why this is happening?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not try [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) instead?

Comment: Hey @Scott, $(document).ready() fires when the dom is loaded but I want the function to be fired when all the content including images etc.. is loaded

Comment: @Onur - Ok, then [`$(window).load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is what you want. I would create a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) to test what you want.  If it works there, then most likely the problem would be in your markup or another script that interfering.

Comment: @Scott you're right, I've just found the problem, another script called jquery vegas is interfering with this function. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is caused by another jquery background plugin which is placed inside $(document).ready()

I moved it inside $(window).load() function, now it works perfect.

I have also moved another function to resize images on the page load. When it was inside $(document).ready() block, sometimes it was malfunctioning if loading time took too long but now it also works great.

```
function resizeImages(){
    //Some Code
}

$(window).load(function(){
    $("#body-mask").fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $.vegas({
        src: backURL , fade:0
    });

    resizeImages();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    //Some Other code
});
```

Comment: Which "background plugin" caused the problem?

Comment: @ppasler it was this jquery vegas plugin but probably it was version 1 by then.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem when mistyped the type attribute in the script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#body-mask").fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Read for `load` and `ready` `functions difference` [What is the difference between $(window).load and $(document).ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182016/what-is-the-difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready)

Comment: If your `page` has more than 1 `window.load` `function` then only 1 will work.

Comment: I have only 1 window.load function, and $(document).ready() is neing fired when the dom is loaded but I want the function to be fired when all the content including images etc.. is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You must call function on initialization like :

```
window.onload = init();
```

in other word modify your code to:

```
window.onload = function () {
$("#body-mask").fadeOut(1000,function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
}();// Added
```

Copy following code in file then open it with firefox

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
alert('saeed')
}();
</script>
```

Comment: This calls the handler immediately without waiting for the document to be fully loaded.