# Hide div with specific class while page is loading then show again after load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to hide an specific div class while page is loading. The structure is..

```
<div id ="container">
<div class="project-item tv"></div>
<div class="project-item radio"></div>
<div class="project-item radio"></div>
<div class="project-item tv"></div>
</div>
```

For example, I want to hide DIV with class radio while page is loading, then show them again after load. Thanks.

Comment: What I would try to do is make it so the div has the class "hidden" (which you can css to be display: none;) and then have some kind of function in the js remove the class after page load.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, set it's CSS value to `display:none`

Then, in a Javascript file, the jQuery solution would be to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#yourdivid").show();
});
```

`$(document).ready()` makes sure that the entire DOM is loaded before the code inside the function is executed

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS

hide div using css

```
div.radio {
    display:none;
}
```

**js**

Show div with class radio on [DOM ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.radio').show();
});
```

---

Show div with class radio on load

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('div.radio').show();
});
```

Read [What is the difference between $(window).load and $(document).ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182016/what-is-the-difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and giving me some tips.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
 div .radio  {display:none;}
</style>

<div id ="container">
<div class="project-item tv"></div>
<div class="project-item radio"></div>
<div class="project-item radio"></div>
<div class="project-item tv"></div>
</div>
```

in JS

```
$().ready(function() {$("div .radio").css("display":"block")});
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="blah" class="hidden"><!-- content --></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function () {
     $('#blah').removeClass('hidden');
 });
```