# Check to see if element exists after DOM is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to detect whether an element is visible after the DOM is ready. This element is a third party widget that loads slower than the page does.

My console.log for 'dom ready' is firing - like it should, but my check to see if the element is visible is returning false, as the element loads after the dom is ready.

Is there a way to listen for elements after the dom has loaded?

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        console.log('dom ready');

        if($(element).is(':visible')){
            console.log('element is visible. do stuff.');
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you able to callback when your widget completes loading?

Comment: See this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182016/what-is-the-difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready

Try using this event: window.onload

Comment: what is the variable `element`??

Comment: `element` is a `<div>`.

Comment: How/Where is "element" defined>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the id from the iframe, or from the document that is being loaded and do something like this..

```
$('#external').load(function(){
    //lets do something when is loaded
    if($(element).is(':visible')){
       console.log('element is visible. do stuff.');
    }
});
```

This will trigger once that script, iframe is done loading

Answer (score 1):

Try to read a documentation, maybe third-party widget's API allows you to attach listener on create event. That would be an ideal solution.

If it is not possible try using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) function:

```
$(function(){
    console.log('dom ready');
    setTimeout(function() {
        if($(element).is(':visible')){
            console.log('element is visible. do stuff.');
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

If 10 ms is not enough, you may increase this interval unless it works, although I don't recommend using this approach.