# making dropdown menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem getting a dropdown image menu to display properly in my browser.
The code is as follows

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jquery test</title>

<style>
#webmenu{
width:340px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
$("body select").msDropDown();
    })
</script>


<select name="webmenu" id="webmenu">
<option value="calendar" title="http://www.abe.co.nz/edit/image_cache/Hamach_300x60c0.JPG"></option>
<option value="shopping_cart" title="http://www.nationaldirectory.com.au/sites/itchnomore/thumbs/screenshot2013-01-23at12.05.50pm_300_60.png"></option>
<option value="cd" title="http://www.mitenterpriseforum.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/MIT_EF_logo_300x60.jpg"></option>

</select>

</body>
</html>
```

I found the original code on github at http://jsfiddle.net/GHzfD/357/ but have not been able to reproduce it - am I making some kind of fundamental mistake?

The page is live at http://www.datatrouble.com/jquery_test.html

Comment: try to intialise `msDropDown()` inside `document.ready()` instead of `window.load`

Comment: I've done that but no luck I'm afraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing `msdropdown` plugins

[msdropdown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/js/msdropdown/jquery.dd.min.js) and [css](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/css/msdropdown/dd.css)

Include this code befor you call `msdropdown`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/css/msdropdown/dd.css">
<script src="http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/js/msdropdown/jquery.dd.min.js"></script>
```

in jsFiddle these external links are included too on the left panel here is snapshot .

[image]

Also read [What is the difference between $(window).load and $(document).ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182016/)

**Update after OP's comment**

You are placing `msdropdown` plugin before you have included jQuery file .

`msdropdown` is a jQuery plugin so jQuery file must be added before the plugin script is called.

So it should look like this:

put your `scripts` at `bottom` of the page and `css` at the `top` to improve page load speed.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/js/msdropdown/jquery.dd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("body select").msDropDown();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I hadn't realised there were missing external links! Thanks for that - I've made those changes to the code and have also gone with putting it in the $(document).ready after reading the article. I've double checked the external link urls and they seem to be fine but it's still not working. Could you offer any more help please?

Comment: Thanks ever so much Tushar! That's done it. I'm new at jQuery and it's these basics that I find frustrating. I'll look back at this and realise how much of a newb I was :)

Comment: @user2840467 Welcome, everybody is newb at some point of time :)