# loading of javascript function only once using .one() API

Tags: jquery, api

I have a questions about JQuery's .one() API, I'm trying to load some functions only once after the document has been fully loaded using .one() API and this doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why...

can I please get some help?

```
$(document).one('load',function(){
// Perform something here...
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$(window).load(function(){ foo(); bar(); });` do what you need? Your functions `foo(); bar();` will run only once. Count on that!

Comment: Oh my god, this works like a charm.. what's the difference between this and doing something like $(document).ready(function(){/.../})? they both achieve the same thing right? I was having a problem where the function inside .ready() executes every time any AJAX call is made within the document..

Comment: Sounds like your AJAX isn't AJAX!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182016/what-is-the-difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works use instead of "load" to "ready" not sure why its not working with the load

```
$(document).one('ready',function(){
    // Perform something here...
    alert("ther you go");
});
```

Keep in mind that "ready" fires before "load".

Comment: This has been deprecated from jQuery 3.0; one() will not work with 'ready' event anymore.

Comment: @Daniel so by what it will be replaced?

Answer (score 2):

Makes no sense to use `.one()` in any of the combination `document ready` or `window load`.

[api.jquery.com/one](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type

you clearly don't expect the `ready` or `load` to trigger twice. Those run once per session so it's quite silly to use `.one()` for this (*artificial*) events.

Also it's good to know that:

```
$(document).one("ready", function(){
  console.log("DOCUMENT SILLY ONE READY");
});

$(function(){ // (DOM ready shorthand)
  console.log("DOCUMENT READY");  // not only will this one run...
});    
              // but also this is the order result:

                    // DOCUMENT READY
                    // DOCUMENT SILLY ONE READY
```

so to conclude, you only need

```
$(function(){
  // DOM is ready to be manipulated
  foo();      
  bar();
});
```

or:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // DOM, metadata, scripts, files, styles, images...etc are load and ready
  foo();      
  bar();        
});
```

and your functions will not run more than once.

Comment: Because `ready` doesn't override each other, if you're using AJAX, the same function may be called on multiple page visits.