# jQuery not working in IE8 and higher

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

using jQuery 1.9.1

The div acts like a container for an image. It has a css styled close icon.
When user clicks on the close icon, it removes the image inside the div and also hides the close icon.

These 2 JS functions work fine in chrome & firefox but not in IE8 & IE11.
What can be done here.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
 <a class="closeCompare" rel="237" style="display:block"></a>
 <img class="imgCompare" src="pics/1.png" style="display:block"></img>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
RemoveDefaultImage(); //hide the ugly X icon that shows up when there is no image
ShowHideRemoveIcon(); //hide the close icon
})

function RemoveDefaultImage() {       
    $(".imgCompare").each(function () {
        if (($(this).attr('src').length) == 0) {
            $(this).css("display", "none");
        }
        else {
            $(this).css("display", "block");
        }
    })
}

function ShowHideRemoveIcon() {        
    $(".closeCompare").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('rel') == 0) {
            $(this).css("display", "none");
        }
        else {
            $(this).css("display", "block");
        }
    })
}
```

These functions fire on page load and also on a click event

Comment: Please explain what's happening in IE. Any error in console?

Comment: If you put an alert() in the document.ready() does it fire in IE?

Comment: @Karl. Nothing happens actually. Both the image and the icon stay there and not hide.

Comment: @Liath. No the alert doesnt fire in IE

Comment: @Qwerty please post how you reference jQuery

Comment: For me, your code is behaving exactly the same in Google Chrome as IE11: http://jsfiddle.net/toy6wnfy/5/. The question makes no sense, what you are saying it is doing (some click functionality) and what the code is doing (hiding based on empty attributes) are two completely different things.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The events fire on page load and also on click. I just put only the function part. But the main prob remains the same, not working in ie but fine in chrome and firefox

Comment: `"These functions fire on page load"` how?

Comment: @Qwerty I think your logic is flawed. What is your exact expected outcome? can you create a http://www.jsfiddle.net that is supposedly working in Chrome/Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

This potentially could fix the problem, but if not you should do it anyway. Change:

```
$(document).ready
```

to

```
$(window).load
```

$(document).ready doesn't wait for images to load: [What is the difference between $(window).load and $(document).ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182016/what-is-the-difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready)

Answer (score 1):

I think you `$(document).ready(function (){ });` is not fired when first time page load. So it is a problem occurred while you are using multiple js libraries on the same page. So you can use only this code.

**Code:**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function (){ });
```