# Bootstrap Modal Pop-Up not showing

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I do not know what I am doing wrong. The modal is not appearing and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried it in jsfiddle and it still does not appear when I load the site. Whatever help will be appreciate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>YesICan</title>
<meta name="description" content="Hello World">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<header>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <h3>Modals in Bootstrap</h3>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</header>

<div class="container">
<!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1">Activate the button</button>-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center">Safety Warning</h3>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">       
                     <p style="text-align:center"> Your computer use can be monitored by others! Consider using a public computer or a friend's computer. Please view more computer safety tips or escape to Google. Then more computer safety tips linked to a page with details about browser history, cache, search history, etc. and escape to Google linked to Google.</p>
                     <p style="text-align:center"> To learn more how to computer safety, click the following link: <br><a href="#">Safety Tips</a></br></p>
                     <!--Wording can be better just for the meantime-->
                    <p style="text-align:center"> If you are not safe, click the following link: <br><a href="http://www.google.com">Get Me Out of Here!</a></br></p>  
                 </div>

                 <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-default" class="btn pull-middle" data-dismiss="modal" class="pagination-centered">Close</a>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <hr>

        <p>
            <small><a href="http://facebook.com/askorama">Like me</a> On facebook</small></p>
        <p> <small><a href="http://twitter.com/wiredwiki">Ask whatever </a> On Twitter</small></p>
        <p> <small><a href="http://youtube.com/wiredwiki">Subscribe me</a> On Youtube</small>

        </p>
    </div> <!-- end container -->
</footer>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You didn't include the JQuery library in your website

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the console, you will notice `undefined is not a function`. This is in reference to you trying to call `$` in the following **before** jQuery is loaded in the `<head>` tag.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Then you have jQuery at the end of the page. If you were to put the jQuery reference in your head above your `script` tag, you should be good to go.

**Notes:**

Doesn't make a HUGE difference but it's more accepted to have your javascript loading at the bottom of the page. I've found it easier to debug or avoid such things. Especially when you are relying on 3rd party libs such as jQuery.

Unless you really need to wait for images and such on the page to load, you should use the `$(document).ready()` event **or** the cleaner `$(function () {});`

More info on the differences can be found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182016/what-is-the-difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the bootstrap javascript (and jQuery) javascript files for this to work.

You can load bootstrap.js from [here](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

And a list of jQuery library's can be found [here](https://code.jquery.com/)

Comment: I do have those Jquery libraries

Comment: I do have those loaded. Here are is what I added to it and it didnt change anything and for some reason did not appear when I asked the question:                                                                                            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">             </script>
          <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Answer (score -1):

First, you are missing a closing `div` tag for the `myModal` div.

Then you are to be sure you have your jQuery libraries all loaded up (`bootstrap.js` and `jquery`).

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have done what you guys said which I already have and it is still not working