# jquery help - initialize Masonry after all images have loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I am using a masonry plugin but my images are overlapping when the page first loads.  If I change the width of the browser they fall into place.  The developer told me to do the following but I am unsure how to "add it: to my custom.js file properly.

I was just told to:

```
// with jQuery
var $container = $(’#container’);

// initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry();
});
```

Can anyone properly format this advice so I can use it?

Comment: This code example contains smart quotes in the first line of code. You should make sure those are regular single or double quotes in your actual code, not smart quotes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

He wants you to use the [imagesLoaded plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded).

Load that plugin

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/3.1.8/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.1/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

and use as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $container = $("#container");

    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.masonry();
    });
});
```

What this does is:

1. Wait for the document to be ready
2. Wait for the images inside the container to have loaded
3. Run masonry on the container

Comment: WOW!  thanks for the great advice.  Your advice seems to be working.

Comment: maybe a bit later, but does this work with dynamically created content and graphs instead of images?

Comment: @Wouter No, not as far as I know. I assume you use ajax for dynamically loaded content. In that case you can use the ajax `complete` event. Your graphs are probably created by a plug-in, it's likely that this plug-in also has an event that fires when the creation has finished.

Comment: @Bram I've made a question about it

Answer (score 5):

You can insert your code in  `$(window).load(function()` and mansonry inizialize after all element are load.

Example:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var $container = $(’#container’);
$container.masonry();
});
```

Comment: difference between document ready and window load: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182016/what-is-the-difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready

Comment: Window load isn't necessary as he's already using images loaded. Remove one or the other.