# Turn JQuery into click event

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code that works fine

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name ='_sft_product_cat[]']").parent().next(".children").css("background", "yellow");
})
});
```

What I am trying to do is turn this into a click event but I cant get it work, I have tried the following

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name = '_sft_product_cat[]']").click(function(){
 $(this).parent().next(".children").css("background", "blue");
return false;
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Remember, the $(document).ready is the first node that is load in a page, because the document is literaly the file html, js or php where your code are in. So, it doesn't make a sense put it into the $(window).load

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182016/what-is-the-difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you miss is closing brackets for the `document.ready` and `window.load` functions. Also you need not use window.load and `document.ready` both , only `document.ready` is sufficient

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name = '_sft_product_cat[]']").click(function(){
 $(this).parent().next(".children").css("background", "blue");
return false;
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="_sft_product_cat[]"/>
</div>
<div class="children">Hello</div>
```

Comment: thanks! soo stupid. I'm using this to actually do a slidetoggle function which thanks to you now works...

Comment: @RamonSchmidtRocha , I agree, I just copy pasted the code that he is having. Its good to mention the other places the code can be improved. Will edit the answer for that. Thanks

Comment: @JonJones Glad to jave helped

Answer (score 0):

Simply you missed closing brackets. Please use any IDE; like [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/)/[WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/?fromMenu) for developing. These IDEs can find this kind of error easily.