# jQuery height is wrong when refreshing in middle of document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I have javascript code which calculates the height of container.

**Two situations:**

Correct Height - When I do a hard refresh at the top of the page.

Incorrect Height - When I do a hard refresh somewhere in the middle of the page.

**jQuery**

```
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
      if (jQuery('.sidebar').length){
        var $sidebar = jQuery('.sidebar');
        var $container = jQuery('.syllabus-container');
        var $writerContainer = jQuery('.writer-container');
        var sideBottom = parseFloat($sidebar.css('top')) + $sidebar.height();
        var contBottom = $container.offset().top + $container.height();
      }
   });
```

I don't really have a live example, but basically the problem lies in that last line, where it does `$container.height()`. Can anyone think of any reason for this?

Comment: SHould probably be doing onload not ready....

Comment: It's likely that you won't get a consistent height either way because the container may not have it's content when this calculation runs. onload is a better option as @epascarello mentioned.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182016/what-is-the-difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use `onload` instead of `ready`. This makes the script wait a little bit longer until everything is loaded in.